# How do I find the address of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception?

Tags: ios, cpu-registers, virtual-memory, mach

In [How do I recover from EXC_BAD_ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19441361/9636), I figured out how to recover from an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, but I had the badly accessed pointer stored in a global. Obviously, this won't scale.  When I run the code in the iOS Simulator (i386), I can see `faultvaddr` register in the `Exception State Registers` section of the debugger when inside my `catch_exception_raise` function. However, its value isn't the same or close to pointer returned from `vm_allocate`. Is there a way to get this value dynamically?

Given the `catch_exception_raise` function below, how would I discover the address that caused the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

```
kern_return_t
catch_exception_raise(mach_port_t exception_port,
                      mach_port_t thread,
                      mach_port_t task,
                      exception_type_t exception,
                      exception_data_t code_vector,
                      mach_msg_type_number_t code_count)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "catch_exception_raise %d\n", exception);
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great amount of detail on that in the OS X and iOS Internals book (http://www.newosxbook.com). Listing 11-21 (ibid) in the book actually shows sample code to do so. In a nutshell, you've two options:

A)  look at the exception itself from the exception data - convert the state to an arm_thread_state, something like so:

```
struct arm_thread_state *atsh = &exc.old_state;
printf ("CPSR is %p, PC is %p, etc.\n", atsh->cpsr, atsh->pc);
```

Or

B) call thread_get_state to the thread port (since you have that right there as argument #2), and get pc (the instruction pointer) or any of the other registers

**EDIT**

I'm not sure how to make A) work, but the following works ([found here](http://uninformed.org/index.cgi?v=4&a=3&p=14)) for B) on the 32-bit iOS Simulator. I'm not sure what the arm register equivalent is for `__faultvaddr`, so you'd have to figure that out before trying arm.

```
// types from thread_status.h
x86_exception_state32_t x86_exception_state32; 
mach_msg_type_number_t sc = x86_EXCEPTION_STATE32_COUNT;

thread_get_state(thread,
                 x86_EXCEPTION_STATE32,
                 (thread_state_t)&x86_exception_state32,
                 &sc);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `&exc.old_state`. `exception_type_t` is just an `int` and `exception_data_t` is just an `int*`.

Comment: You need to get the exception structure. You can get that by reading a mach_msg from the exception port. The code (in the very same listing) demonstrates that.

Comment: Sorry, what listing are you talking about? The one from http://stackoverflow.com/q/19441361/9636 ? Sorry, I've just started doing this work in my spare time, and things are sparsely documented.